# Same PHP variable having 2 different values

Tags: php, jquery, python, ajax, apache

I'm making a simple site using a local apache webserver with cgi so I can run my python scripts. I also am using jQuery to make AJAX requests to the python scripts so I can run the script asynchronously. I'm also using PHP to simulate a login button so users can login to the website. Problem is that after the users logs in, it displays the ID of the user, and I want this same ID to be passed to the python script as a parameter, where the script will take it and return something else. Although I'm using the same exact PHP variable, the variable I'm passing to the python script is similar, but not the same as the one it displays when the user logs in.

PHP Code to display ID after user logs in:

```
echo "Welcome back" . "</br> </br>" . $picture ."</br>". $steamprofile['personaname'] . "</br>" .$state .  "</br>".  "Steam ID: ". $steamprofile['steamid'] . "</br>";
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">Steam Profile</a>'  . "</br> </br>" . "<form action=\"steamauth/logout.php\" method=\"post\"><input value=\"Logout\" type=\"submit\" /></form>";
```

PHP Variable that's passed to python script (using J

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#steambutton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/Steap.py",
            data: {steamid: <?php echo $steamprofile['steamid']?>},
            success: function(response) {
                $("#steamdiv").html(response);  
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

As you can see in both code snippets the variable that's having two different values is the `$steamprofile['steamid']`. These two code snippets as almost next to each other, and I don't change the value of `$steamprofile['steamid']` anywhere after the first script is executed. Why is this happening? It seems really weird for the variable to have two similar values.

As an example, this is the ID of the user after they login (from the first code):
`76561198041778794`

This is the ID that's passed to the python script from the second code, however:
`76561198041778800`

Comment: How is this ID generated?

Comment: Did you try to pass the ID as string? May be it is a type conversion problem, because of the long number.

Comment: @thanpa The ID is generated when the user logs in to a third party site from our local site.
@Henrik I tried your suggestion: `data: {steamid: <?php echo sprintf('%s',$steamprofile['steamid'])?>}`, but the same ID is still coming up, and it's not the same as the first one.

Comment: @VarunIyer What is about the python script? Does it take the parameter as string? You have to use quotes in the javascript to declare it as string.

Comment: @Henrik Just to test what value comes in as a parameter I have this code:
`import cgi 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
steeam = form.getfirst('steamid')
def test(sm):
 return sm

print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print "<h3>"
print test(steeam)
print "</h3>"`

Comment: - Is the id changing with every refresh you do at the page is it only 2 different ids you always see?
- Is the javascript in a different file? Can you explain more in detail how close are the two portions of code you posted?

Comment: @VarunIyer You can use `print type(steeam)` in the python script to get the type of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for passing the data (added quotes to pass it as string):

```
data: {steamid: "<?php echo $steamprofile['steamid']?>"},
```